# android: check if a string is an english dictionary?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

Can I check if a string is an english dictionary word present in androids system dictionary?

```
String word = "myWord";
```

How can I find out if myWord is in the english dictionary?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744792/access-user-dictionary-android

Comment: That's the user dictionary. OP should look at the spell-checker service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to access the dictionary specifically. You could use the spell-checker service:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/textservice/SpellCheckerService.Session.html#onGetSuggestions(android.view.textservice.TextInfo, int)

Here's a tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Comment: The samples can be found in [Github](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/SpellChecker)